# Can pyqubo and qiskit be used together?

Tags: qiskit, optimization, pyqubo

I used Pyqubo to create an optimisation problem with an objective function and some constraints, but I want to use Qiskit to run QAOA/VQE on my model. Is it possible to call my Pyqubo model into Qiskit? Qiskit has a nice way of easily calling cplex/docplex models; I'd like something similar with Pyqubo. Is it possible?